# Using SQLite, how can I search for chars that include a ', similar to OLE DB .Parameters?

Tags: c#, sqlite

Using SQLite, how can I search for chars that include a ', similar to OLE DB .Parameters?

This works to find bruce and baseball:

```
string stCmdString = "SELECT fstInfo FROM PadTable WHERE fstInfo LIKE '%bruce%' AND fstInfo LIKE '%baseball%'"
```

Not sure how to find bruce's and baseball.

I know it can be done by using two single quote marks ... but this is a bit of a hassle to read every char of all new entries (or searches) to the database before storing the.

The use of .Parameters in OLE DB fixes this problem.  Is there an equivalent for SQLite?

Comment: Yes, SqliteParameter with an SqliteCommand will escape strings automatically.

Comment: If you are not using OLE DB, what driver are you using to access SQLite?

Comment: using System.Data.SQLite;